# GCC C++ string on stack

Tags: c++, string

I'm running an embedded device with c++ (and yes I keep dynamic allocations to an absolute minimum). But I was wondering:

In C

```
void Do_Something(const char* const pString);

void f()
{
  Do_Something("some string");
}
```

`pString` is actually an array with is located on the task stack.

in C++

```
void Do_Something(const string my_string);

void f()
{
  Do_Something("some string");
}
```

I'd assume `my_string` only the pointer to the string is located on the stack. The actual content is located on the heap right?

First question is there anyway to place the string on the stack (without using `char *`)?

All STL classes like string call new internally to allocate memory on the heap. Now new throws an exception in case of failure. So to actually be on the safe side I'd have to do something like this

```
try
{
  Do_Something("some string");
}
catch(const exception& ex)
{
  //Exception handling
}
```

If the string goes on the heap I'd have to do this for **all** calls to `Do_something()`. Is there a better way?

***Edit***: Thx for all your very helpful answers. That gives me some thinking for the next days :)

Comment: [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) if you have a compiler that supports C++17

Comment: "pString is actually an array" - nope, it's a pointer.

Comment: You catch exceptions at the highest posible level in  your code, not at the lowest. Exceptions are not analogous to function return values. Wrapping a single function call in a try/catch block is almost always a sign that your program is badly designed.

Comment: In this particular example, the string in C will probably end up in a section with the other global and static constants. The C++ string should use the Small String Optimization to store the content in the same object on the stack, instead of making a heap allocation. In libstdc++, it currently will store up to 15 bytes of content before making a heap allocation.

Comment: @joelw assuming SSO is being used at all. It is not a requirement of the standard, and not all implementations use it.

Comment: Pass `std::string` by reference, not by value (copy).

Answer (score 2):

`std::string_view` is preferable if available.

If not, you can overload `Do_Something` with a version that will accept a string literal in a type safe way.

```
class Do_Something_For_Real {
    template <size_t N> friend void Do_Something(const char (&)[N]);
    void operator () (const char * const pString, size_t N) {
        //...
    }
};

template <size_t N>
void Do_Something(const char (&pString)[N]) {
    Do_Something_For_Real()(pString, N);
}
```

If you must have something with the same semantics as `std::string`, you can instantiate `std::basic_string` with a custom allocator that returned "stack" allocated memory when asked.

```
template <size_t N>
struct fake_allocator {
    char mem_[N];
    void * allocate (size_t, const void * = 0) { return mem_; }
    ...
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code example in C

```
void Do_Something(const char* const pString);
void f()
{
Do_Something("some string");
}
```

Adds a constant pointer to a constant char on the stack (more precisely in the stack-frame of the function Do_Something). When calling it in that way, you pass exactly that kind of pointer to a string which is located in the data area of your program. So when talking about embedded systems, then it is placed in the .data area of your binary (this might vary between some compilers).

Your C++ code

```
 void Do_Something(const string my_string);

 void f()
 {
    Do_Something("some string");
 }
```

uses call by value, i.e., you create a copy of a string object dynamically on the stack, which further might allocate memory on the heap. So when passing now a constant as here, the compiler creates this string object dynamically, too. 
Further, the STL classes allocate dynamically memory on the heap, when their size rises up. To prevent this, you can provide an allocator, which does not allocate memory or takes it from a dedicated memory pool, or does what ever you implement.

Of course you need to deal when your code tries to exceed the limits, but you should design your SW in a way that this cannot happen or at least reduces the probability to an absolute minimum. E.g., by checking length of inputs, etc. if it fits to your buffers.